# Scrapy - simple captcha solving example

Tags: python, scrapy, captcha

When looking online for Scrapy to solve a captcha, I see no good example to even start with.

I've created a very basic captcha page. http://145.100.108.148/login3/

Is there someone with a working example to solve this, or at least configured Scrapy in a decent fashion trying to solve it.

Comment: this url is not working right now but I use this APIs, It has solved all the types of captchas that I had: https://metabypass.tech

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solving the captcha itself is easy using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.0.0/) and [Python Tesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract). The hard part was to realize how to handle cookies (`PHPSESSID`). Here's complete working example for your case (using Python 2):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                         
import io                                                                       
import urllib2                                                                  

from PIL import Image                                                           
import pytesseract                                                              
import scrapy                                                                   


class CaptchaSpider(scrapy.Spider):                                             
    name = 'captcha'                                                            

    def start_requests(self):                                                   
        yield scrapy.Request('http://145.100.108.148/login3/',                  
                             cookies={'PHPSESSID': 'xyz'})                      

    def parse(self, response):                                                  
        img_url = response.urljoin(response.xpath('//img/@src').extract_first())

        url_opener = urllib2.build_opener()                                     
        url_opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'PHPSESSID=xyz'))               
        img_bytes = url_opener.open(img_url).read()                             
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes))                                 

        captcha = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)                              
        print 'Captcha solved:', captcha                                        

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(                                
            response, formdata={'captcha': captcha},                            
            callback=self.after_captcha)                                        

    def after_captcha(self, response):                                          
        print 'Result:', response.body
```

Comment: @ErikTol You have to install Tesseract command line tool. If you are on Ubuntu/Debian system, it's in `tesseract-ocr` package.

Comment: I tried pytesseract for a simple number in an image, plain text, but it returned a wrong number! not even a real captcha which is usually noisy or includes rotated characters. did you guys really get a decent result from this library? I found it a weak OCR, not even close to a good captcha-Solver

Answer (score 6):

here is a solution works well on straight images

```
best = ("https://my captcha url")
f = open('captcha.jpg','wb')
f.write(urllib.urlopen(best).read())
f.close()

import pytesseract
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

from pdf2image import convert_from_path
#img = Image.open('captcha.jpg')
image = cv2.imread('captcha.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

#gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)

filename = "{}.png".format("temp")
cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('temp.png'))
print text
```